# Counting likes in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new at Firebase and I fall into two difficulties right now.

Part of my web-app load photos and collect 'likes - ♥' for them

This is my simple structure in Realtime Database, this is a simplified model:

```
"photos": {
  "-h42Z1w9wD4G7AtPcdPb": {
    "author": "9f0f5c90-fa9c-47b9-9757-4fecf640e78c",
    "path": "/images/9932988.jpg"
  },
  "-d9n0ME8H7zYvCBu9pf3": {
    "author": "5db561db-56f9-4d5b-8b32-30d487c03dbf",
    "path": "/images/9865733.jpg"
  },
  <...>
}

"likes": {
  "-s2kEFg6U02KzKf8w0Hi": {
    "from": "9f0f5c90-fa9c-47b9-9757-4fecf640e78c",
    "to": "-d9n0ME8H7zYvCBu9pf3"
  },
  "-rh186npGIuXqZ58KX3v": {
    "from": "5db561db-56f9-4d5b-8b32-30d487c03dbf",
    "to": "-h42Z1w9wD4G7AtPcdPb"
  }
  <...>
}
```

1. How can I count ON THE BACKEND how many 'likes' put a user with id "9f0f5c90-fa9c-47b9-9757-4fecf640e78c", or how many 'likes' got a photo with id "-s2kEFg6U02KzKf8w0Hi"?
2. I load 10 photos with query.limitToLast(10). How can I load next 10 photos: from last 11 to 20, then from 21 to 30 for my pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to be perplexed with the same thing as you. Thank God for [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) now!

Check out this [sample on Github](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count) that shows you how to count the number of children and update the counter in a transaction. Though, I would like to add that Cloud Functions are still in Beta.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this technique, it really works.

But now it seems to me that Realtime Database is just an plain JS object. And there is no advantage to NoSQL database (like MongoDB), such as an aggregate() or comparisons. This is true?

Comment: I personally adore NoSQL databases. You have to put in a little effort in the beginning, but once you get the database structured to suit your queries, then you'd see how blazingly fast NoSQL databases can be compared to plain old SQL style joins and tables. This is specially true for Firebase Realtime Database. From my extensive experience with it, I can vouch that it really is 'realtime'! You'd be amazed at the speed with which data can be retrieved and updated to the Realtime Database! :)

Comment: As far as comparison and aggregating is concerned, you really can structure your database to suit your need without it. That's why NoSQL databases are so flexible. Also, if you found that my answer was appropriate for your question, then please do accept it. It'll make it easier for others with the same problem to find this solution. And trust me, I have come across many people who have been asking the exact same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I think now this is the thinking approach for solving similar cases.